# How to select an element in an array based on the value of a contained object field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array with 3 elements with each element of the array having 2 objects and looking like this:

text{field1: 'xyz', field2: 'def'}
metadata{id: 42, timestamp: '02-25-2018'}

On a react app, I have a list of elements with each one displaying array[i].text.field1 . I would like to implement a click handler where when the user clicks an element, it switches a piece of the state (based on the element they clicked). How do I index into the right element in my array based on the nested field1 value? Let me know if I need to add more color here.

Comment: You do need to add more "color", what have you tried, where it failed, what errors did you get...

Answer (score 0):

Create **Element** stateless component and pass element data from array as props. Using closure pass this props to onClick handler.

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
  const { text: { field1, field2 } } = props;
  return <div>
           <h1
              onClick={((e) => onFieldClick(e, props))}
           >
           {field1}
           </h1>
  </div>;
};

const onFieldClick = (e, props) => {
  alert(props.text.field1);
}
```

> [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6dwub4)